# easy-rules: is there an if-else rule?

Tags: java, rule-engine, easy-rules

I am trying to work with easy-rules.

Can we have an `if-else` rule executed using easy-rules?

I have checked on `ActivationRuleGroup` and `ConditionalRuleGroup`, but it seems it's only all `if`'s.

Answer (score 1):

All rules are **if-then**, there is no else; it's a different kind of thinking.  Rules are not meant to replace just any logic you see in your average source code.  They're best implemented for things akin to long switch-case-like logic or parameter-driven logic. Income tax forms are an example of a parameter-driven use-case.

If you need three actions based on the value of one fact, for example:

```
if age < 16
    action: discount = 15%
else if age >= 16 and age <= 65
    action: discount = 0%
else 
    action: discount = 20%
```

Then you simply write 3 rules:

```
when age < 16
    action: discount = 15%

when age >= 16 and age <= 65
    action: discount = 0%

when age > 65
    action: discount = 20%
```

The Composite rules are used for handling **groups** of rules.

`ConditionalRuleGroup` has one "primary" rule such that when it evaluates to `true` (triggered), then the remainder of the rules in the group are fired otherwise the group is skipped.

I use `UnitRuleGroup` for form-like validation.  All of the data from a form is put into the `facts` and the validation rules are fired.  If **any one** of the rules is false, then the whole group returns false and the form is deemed invalid.